# Converting Integer to ObservableValue<Integer> in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

How to convert `Integer` To `ObservableValue<Integer>` in javafx 2.0 and later ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

We use  a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(*integer value*);` and store the value in a `ObservableValue<Integer>` reference.

```
ObservableValue<Integer> obsInt = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(intValue);
```

---

**Update**

Starting JavaFX 8, you can also do the following :

```
ObservableValue<Integer> obsInt = new SimpleIntegerProperty(intValue).asObject();
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way.

```
new SimpleIntegerProperty(integer_value).asObject()
```

Comment: `#asObject()` was added in JavaFX 8

Comment: One subtle issue, if you need the `Integer` (object) as opposed to the primitive `int` (pehaps to allow null references), you have to use the `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Integer>` and not the `SimpleIntegerProperty`

Answer (score 7):

if you  use tableview do this :
just change Integer to Number

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Sockets,Number> key;
...
key.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().socketIdProperty());
```

Comment: Same for Double values.

Answer (score 4):

`IntegerProperty` implements `ObservableValue<Number>` not `ObservableValue<Integer>`. So you should do:

```
// Here Person is a class and age is a variable of type IntegerProperty
ObservableValue<Number> ob = Person.age;
```