# String can not be casted to ObservableValue

Tags: java, casting, javafx-8, observable

I got a String in my model that I want to keep track of (the String represents a continent). If the continent changes, a ListView should be updated in the gui with the correct countries for that continent.

```
String selectedContinent;
ObservableValue continent = (ObservableValue) selectedContinent;
continent.addListener( ......
```

Obviously I get  error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to ObservableValue.

I've previously used ObservableList, etc.. But this ObservableValue is new to me. After searching I found alot related to Property etc.. but nothing I could learn from sorta.

Comment: look at the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413040/converting-integer-to-observablevalueinteger-in-javafx

Comment: Can you use [StringProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html) instead? Not familiar with javafx myself, but a quick Google search makes it seems like you can use StringProperty (which implements ObservableValue via Property interface) to wrap your selectedContinent String and then call addListener on it.

Comment: What is the added value that a Property has then? I'll see what I can do.

Comment: You should be able to create a new instance of StringProperty and call setValue(selectedContinent) on it to wrap your selectedContinent in it, then you can take advantage of the methods of StringProperty (addLIstener, etc.)

Comment: The added value that a `StringProperty` has is that it is an `ObservableValue`, so you can add listeners to it. A `String` is not an `ObservableValue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a StringProperty instead. You can't instantiate StringProperty since it is an abstract class so use SimpleStringProperty.

e.g.

```
SimpleStringProperty selectedContinent = new SimpleStringProperty;
selectedContinent.setValue(selection);
selectedContinent.addListener(....
```