# JavaFX How can I access Application object in Controller?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a ***simple*** javaFX program. In `HelloApplication` I want to do the logic, and in `HelloController` I want to listen to button clicks which then execute methods inside the `HelloApplcation`.

**HelloApplication.java:**

```
Timeline timeline;
@FXML
HelloController HC;
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
private int counter=0;
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 640, 480);
        stage.setTitle("Program!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        StartCounter("start");
}
public void StartCounter(String status)
    {
        HC = fxmlLoader.getController();
        if(timeline==null) {
            timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), ev -> {
                HC.getCmd().setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                counter++;
            }));
            timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        }else{
            if(status=="stop")
                timeline.stop();
            else if(status=="start")
                timeline.play();
        }
}
```

**HelloController.java:**

```
  HelloApplication helloApp=new HelloApplication(); //this creates another instance...
 @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        helloApp.StartCounter("stop");
    }
```

But how can I access **HelloApplication** object that was created on `launch()`?
Something like `loader.getApplication()` would be perfect instead of creating a new object in controller (which doesn't work anyway).

Right now, after mouse click the helloApp.StartCounter() causes:
***java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException***

Comment: @jewelsea Thank you for proposing a different, better approach. I agree 100% with everything you said and I will do it following your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How can I access the Application object in Controller?**

To directly answer your question.

1. Save the application instance to a static variable in the application `init` method.
2. Provide a static accessor method to access it.

This is kind of like a singleton pattern, but the application instance is created by the `launch` method.

```
public class AccessibleApp extends Application {
    private static AccessibleApp applicationInstance;

    public static AccessibleApp getApplicationInstance() {
        return applicationInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        applicationInstance = this;
    }

    // other app functionality ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Then the application can be accessed from any class using:

```
AccessibleApp.getApplicationInstance()
```

**Issues with your sample code and approach**

1. You should not create another application instance.

   The [application lifecycle](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) javadoc notes there should be only one application instance in the JVM and this will be created by the invocation of the `launch()` method.

   The `launch()` method can only be called once for the JVM process.
2. There should never be an `@FXML` annotation in an Application class.

   `@FXML` is only used in a controller and the application class should not also be a controller.
3. Your overall approach is incorrect:

   > in HelloController I want to listen to button clicks which then execute methods inside the HelloApplcation

   You should not do this.

   The application class is responsible for the application lifecycle. Unless it is a trivial self-contained hello world style application, it should not be doing anything else. It definitely should not be servicing fxml controller callbacks.

**Recommended Approach**

Perform your application logic either directly in the controller or in a dedicated service class.

1. Write a Counter class that has an integer property for the counter value and a timeline.
2. Provide start and stop methods on the class, do not use a string status for that.
3. In the controller create a Counter instance and start and stop it on user interaction.
4. In the controller initialize method, [bind the display field text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546433/javafx-binding-a-textproperty-eg-label-to-a-simple-integer) to the counter value.

Rather than trying to debug and fix your current code, I recommend you work on implementing the suggested approach instead.

To understand such approaches more, see:

- [Applying MVC With JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)
- [How to apply MVC in JavaFX](https://edencoding.com/mvc-in-javafx/)

Comment: Thank you, I implemented your suggestion and everything look waaay better now, and works too ;)