# JavaFX TableView Integer not displaying while String items are

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a program with these columns:

```
showNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Show, String>("ShowName"));
epsWatchedColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Show, Integer>("EpsWatched;"));
showStatusColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Show, String>("ShowStatus"));
```

The getters are called
getShowName(), getEpsWatched(), and getShowStatus() which get the variables showName, epsWatched, and showStatus.

What's wrong here? The strings display but not the ints.

Comment: @jewelsea instead of int didn't do anything (not sure why it would, it's a wrapper class). Also how would I write a lamba for this? I've never used them before (I know of them, just haven't used them), and the example thread you listed is a bit hard for me to follow. I got: showNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getShowName());
 When I tried to mess with it, but this (probably obviously) gives a type mismatch error of cannot convert from String to ObervableValue<String>.

Comment: that was the issue lol, can you write that as an answer so I can credit you for answering this question?

Comment: Integer vs int was just a guess.  You can rely on the autoboxing behavior most of the time, and in this case I guess it didn’t matter. But int and Integer are not the same thing and I don’t like to trust autoboxing if I don’t have to (just personal preference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a “;” in the string passed to the property value factory, it should not be there.

This is wrong:

```
new PropertyValueFactory<Show, Integer>("EpsWatched;")
```

PropertyValueFactory lookup strings and property names should follow Java bean naming conventions.  For more info, see:

- [Javafx PropertyValueFactory not populating Tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035478/javafx-propertyvaluefactory-not-populating-tableview)

Normally, I’d close the question as a duplicate of the above question, however, the asker requested a specific answer and had some additional questions, so this answer addresses those directly.

It is recommended to use a lambda rather than a PropertyValueFactory, as any errors will be detected and reported accurately by the compiler rather than failures at runtime.  For a thorough analysis, see:

- [Java: setCellValuefactory; Lambda vs. PropertyValueFactory; advantages/disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049734/java-setcellvaluefactory-lambda-vs-propertyvaluefactory-advantages-disadvant/38050982#38050982)

> how would I write a lamba for this?

In your model class declare the property and provide an accessor for it:

```
public class Show {
    private final IntegerProperty numEpisodes = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public final IntegerProperty numEpisodesProperty() {
        return numEpisodes;
    }
}
```

Use the property accessor in a lambda to define the cell value factory:

```
TableColumn<Show, Integer> numEpisodesCol = new TableColumn<>();
numEpisodesCol.setCellValueFactory(
    data -> data.getValue().numEpisodesProperty().asObject()
);
```

See also:

- [Converting Integer to ObservableValue<Integer> in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413040/converting-integer-to-observablevalueinteger-in-javafx)

Comment: that was it, thanks